# Order of using technologies during Cricket's review

Tags: cricket, officiating, technology, video-review

In cricket, during wicket review by third-umpire in Ashes 2013, the following technologies are used:

```
1.Hot Spot
2.Hawk eye prediction
3.Snicko Meter
```

Is there any order in using these systems. I mean, as far as I have seen, umpires are analysing only hotspot at first, hawkeye in second and snicko in third. It may be either LBW review or catch review, this order is being used. Is there any reason for using them in order?

Comment: Snickometer was not used as part of the DRS in the 2013 Ashes. Umpires would use the sound feed to try and discern whether there was any noise that indicated an edge, but this was not fed into Snickometer (although, for purely interest's sake, later replays on the TV broadcast were able to apply Snickometer for extra analysis).

Comment: Don't forget old-fashioned video. They always/usually start with that, I believe. (First the bowler's front foot, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although i cant cite an official view on this but i think the order of using different technologies in **DRS** is based on logic of eliminating the options.
**DRS** is mostly used in 3 situations, "**caught behind wicket**", "**caught by close-in fielders**" & "**LBW**".

In the first two situations above, there is no need of **hawk-eye**. So the sequence will/should be
1)**Check for No ball**
2)**A slow motion close-in camera replay**(If the edge is clearly visible via an actual match feed than the **hotspot** is just an additional closing confirmation. If not, then **hotspot** is the crucial confirmation)
3)**Sound feed from the stump mic**(Again because real feed confirmation is better than a processed technological one. If the edge is clear & distinct then hotspot will seal the deal)
4)**Hotspot**
Note that as yet, **snickometer** has not been incorporated in **DRS**

In case of **LBW**, the sequence will/should be
1)**Check for No ball**
2)**A slow-mo close-in camera replay**(To check for an inside edge before hitting the pad. If clearly visible, then the next **hotspot** will confirm it & hence no need of **hawk-eye**)
3)**Hotspot**(If the inside edge is visible, **hotspot** will be the closing confirmation. If not then **hotspot** evidence will be the crucial confirmation required for Not Out)
4)**Hawkeye**(If there is "absolutely" no clear evidence of an inside edge, **Hawkeye** evidence becomes crucial for decision making. In case of an "inconclusive" inside edge, a **Hawkeye** showing ball going wide of the stumps or not hitting in line will make **hotsopt** irrelevant)
In case of LBW, hawkeye is checked after hotspot because the trajectory estimate of the ball depends on where it hits first. So, in case of inside edge, it will take the hit on the bat & estimate the trajectory, which if it hits the stump, gives the impression of OUT